# Best place for Ubuntu using WSL?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions

Where's the best place to ask questions about networking under Ubuntu using WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux)?
It seems like candidates are here, Super User, and Ask Ubuntu.
The question relates to a work-from-home situation, not a professionally-managed environment, so Network Engineering is probably off the table.

Comment: I don't have a "best place" answer, but off-the-cuff, U&L's scope says "Note that Ubuntu posts are a special case. If your question applies to Ubuntu only, or you're looking for answers that are Ubuntu-specific, you should post it on the Ask Ubuntu Stack Exchange site.". You explicitly call out Ubuntu; are your questions Ubuntu-specific?

Comment: @JeffSchaller - hard to say whether the questions are Ubuntu-specific of WSL-specific. Based on answers I got at the Super User meta, I think I'll start with Super User and spiral out from there (I'll be sure to lot have cross-postings up simultaneously).